# Change the Text Color of UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to change the **`text color`** of a label in the cell when **Current Date == Facebook Birthday** List Date.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` id did this

```
if([curdatemonthstring isEqualToString:[[totalbirthlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
{
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}
```

This works to change the color but when I scroll it changes back to the old color. How can I fix this?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *simpleTableidentifier=@"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableidentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableidentifier]autorelease];

    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];


    contentview = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
    [contentview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,80)];


    //Display Friends Name
    nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init]autorelease];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(76, 5, 200, 45)];
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Politica" size:20]];
    [nameLabel setText:[[[monthdataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];

    if([curdatemonthstring isEqualToString:[[totalbirthlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    }

    [contentview addSubview:nameLabel];

[cell.contentView addSubview:contentview];

    return cell;

    [birthdaylist reloadData];




}
```

Comment: please provide full code.

Comment: I think you have written it in the if(cell == nil) condition

Comment: Specifically show where you're creating the cell, the colour reseting it most likely because the cell is not being created correctly.

Comment: provide the whole code in CellForRowAtIndexPath.It will be more helpful.

Comment: why are you reloading table in each cellForRow call?

Comment: because,I used Subview for Posting and Sharing.If click any cell,this cell is Expanded.

Comment: It probably won't make any difference, but your `[birthdaylist reloadData];` is never called. After you return something from a method, it doesn't go any further. And does it happen immediately when you try scrolling, or does it only happen when you scroll so much that the cell is going outside of the window and back in again? And you shouldn't reload table inside cellForRow: anyway. This will probably end in an eternal loop of doom.

Answer (score 0):

Because tableview reuses it's cells while scrolling, the issue mostly is because you are writing the logic above inside `if(!cell)`condition.

Comment: cannot change the color.

Comment: Are you resetting the colour of the text anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

To rule out potential problems with data try replacing

```
if([curdatemonthstring isEqualToString:[[totalbirthlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
```

with

```
if(indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 15)
```

Do you always see the colour of rows 0, 1 and 15 set properly?
Could it be that totalbirthlistArray changes unintentionally between scrolls, say in     [birthdaylist reloadData] call?

Comment: I remove that [birthdayList reloaddata].but,no changes.

Comment: As Rheven pointed out [birthdaylist reloadData] is never called in this function and has no effect (maybe you call it elsewhere?). Have you tried replacing if([curdatemonthstring isEqualToString...]) condition with a hardcoded one, like in my example?

Comment: yes,but all text of indexpath.row==0,1,15 changed to purple color.

Comment: You set colours in arbitrary rows (0,1,15). These colours don't "sip" into other rows as you scroll, nor the colour in (0,1,15) changes. If you replace temp conditional with your one then colours are not set properly. That indicates to me that your conditional doesn't work as you'd expect. Do you think this is an explanation?

Comment: It would be great if you could either accept one of the provided answers or write and accept your own answer to your resolved question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace your cellForRowAtIndexPath with this.I think, this will solves your issue.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
static NSString *simpleTableidentifier=@"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableidentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableidentifier]autorelease];

contentview = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
[contentview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,80)];


//Display Friends Name
nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init]autorelease];
[nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(76, 5, 200, 45)];
nameLabel.tag = 1;
[nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Politica" size:20]];
[nameLabel setText:[[[monthdataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];


[contentview addSubview:nameLabel];

[cell.contentView addSubview:contentview];

}

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

UILabel *nameLabel = [cell.contentView viewWihtTag:1];
if([curdatemonthstring isEqualToString:[[totalbirthlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
{
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}

return cell;

[birthdaylist reloadData]; //I don't what is the use of this.
```

}

Comment: Sorry,I removed the reloaddata.

Comment: did you get the required output?